Problems with CORS when using Google OAuth2 in Spring boot/React app
I'm working on a React frontend that communicates with a Spring Boot backend. My goal is to secure certain endpoints on my Spring Boot server using JWT, which includes role information.
Current Setup:
Google OAuth2 Login: After a user logs in via Google, the JWT provided by Google is available in the console, but I'm unable to retrieve the JWT from my backend app, which contains role information.
Spring Boot Configuration:
My SecurityFilterChain is configured to allow CORS, disable CSRF, and authenticate all requests except for login and OAuth2 routes.
I’m using a custom OAuth2UserService and redirecting to /token on successful login.
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())) // Enable CORS
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/login/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userService(customOAuth2UserService))
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/token", true))
        .build();
}
 @Bean
    public UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000"); // Allow your frontend origin
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:3000"); // Allow your frontend origin
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }



User Controller:
The /token endpoint is supposed to generate and return a JWT containing the user's roles.
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    private final JwtUtils jwtTokenUtil;

    @GetMapping("/token")
    public LoginResponse token(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
        loginResponse.setToken(jwtTokenUtil.createToken(oAuth2User.getAttribute("email")));
        return loginResponse;
    }
}

CORS Configuration: CORS is configured to allow requests from http://localhost:3000, which is my React frontend.
Frontend: I'm using @react-oauth/google for Google authentication. After a successful login, I attempt to send the Google JWT to my backend to retrieve the custom JWT.
axiosInstance.get('/token', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${credentialResponse}`
    }
})
.then(response => {
    Cookies.set('access_token', response.data.jwt);
    console.log('Login Successful');
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('Login Failed Inner');
    console.log(error);
});

Problem:
When I try to log in using my frontend app, I encounter a CORS
Issue:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&scope=profile%20email&state=...&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/token') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I also receive an ERR_FAILED 302 (Found) error, and the axios request fails with a network error.
Additional Details:
The redirection URI in my Google Cloud Console matches the one in my application.properties file (http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google).
I have added "proxy": "http://localhost:8080" in my package.json file.
When I test the /token endpoint using just the backend (without the React frontend), everything works fine—the user is saved to my database, and I receive the correct JWT.
Question:
How can I resolve this CORS issue and successfully retrieve the JWT from my backend after Google login?
Is there anything wrong with my current setup or approach that might be causing this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You are asking about cors but then you post all code except for your cors code? corsConfigurationSource() why?

I added my cors configuration

Requests to applications wiith oauth2Login are authorized with session cookies, not Bearer tokens. And this cookies are flagged with SameSite, so you probably want a reverse proxy instead of CORS configuration. Read this article for SPA, Spring and OAuth2. Last, the tokens you get from Google are probably opaque (not JWTs), and their audience probably Google APIs (not your resource servers, once you have some). Use your own authorization server.

As pointed out in the above comment, you have completely missunderstood how google login works, as you think that google will act as your authentication and authorization server for you. Which is not true. Google will authenticate the user, but not authorize the user. We cant in comments explain to you how this actually works, you need to read the spring docs or the article posted in previous comments. As outh2login logs you in with oauth2 but then uses cookies to athorize the user. So your home made security wont work
